# PG Utils not supported problem while installing Ready2Use CMDBuild

Tags: java, postgresql, installation

I am trying to install Ready2Use version 2.2-3.3.2 using the war file. The environment is as prescribed in the Technical-manual document.

1. JDK ver 17
2. Tomcat 10
3. Postgres 10.20
   The error it is showing is "**pg utils are not supported on this os =< Mac OS X > : you will have to import db manually**". I tried to look for the issue on the web but can't find any pointers
   The console output is as below:

19:00:01.554 ERROR o.c.utils.gui.GuiCommandRunner - error executing install
org.cmdbuild.dao.DaoException: Error while configuring the database
at org.cmdbuild.dao.config.inner.DatabaseCreator.configureDatabase(DatabaseCreator.java:201)
at org.cmdbuild.utils.cli.utils.DatabaseUtils.createDatabase(DatabaseUtils.java:42)
at org.cmdbuild.utils.cli.utils.DatabaseUtils.createDatabase(DatabaseUtils.java:36)
at org.cmdbuild.utils.cli.utils.DatabaseUtils.createDatabase(DatabaseUtils.java:32)
at org.cmdbuild.utils.gui.GuiCommandRunner$InstallHelper.lambda$install$10(GuiCommandRunner.java:319)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.cmdbuild.dao.DaoException: java.lang.RuntimeException: pg utils are not supported on this os =< Mac OS X > : you will have to import db manually
at org.cmdbuild.dao.config.inner.DatabaseCreator.restoreDump(DatabaseCreator.java:409)
at org.cmdbuild.dao.config.inner.DatabaseCreator.configureDatabase(DatabaseCreator.java:185)
... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: pg utils are not supported on this os =< Mac OS X > : you will have to import db manually
at org.cmdbuild.utils.lang.CmExceptionUtils.runtime(CmExceptionUtils.java:68)
at org.cmdbuild.utils.postgres.PostgresHelperImpl.checkOs(PostgresHelperImpl.java:114)
at org.cmdbuild.utils.postgres.PostgresHelperImpl.(PostgresHelperImpl.java:105)
at org.cmdbuild.utils.postgres.PostgresHelperConfigImpl$PostgresHelperBuilder.buildHelper(PostgresHelperConfigImpl.java:222)
at org.cmdbuild.utils.postgres.PostgresUtils.dumpContainsSchema(PostgresUtils.java:78)
at org.cmdbuild.dao.config.inner.DatabaseCreator.restoreDump(DatabaseCreator.java:349)
... 6 common frames omitted

Answer (score 1):

it means you have to configure the database manually either via command line, pgadmin or another db management software.

have you read the Technical manual? you can get it from here [technical manual](https://www.cmdbuild.org/file/manuali/technical-manual-in-english)

in page 17, whether it win or mac sometime face some problem with database configuration. install postgis, create gis schema and restore the dump file via pg_restore